# Send variable array to controller via ajax(Laravel)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

i try to send variable array to return exact data from database based on array given but its give me error in console . It success when passing  only one value of array but when i passing two or more value of array it show error in console

irel__ref_category was from my model . here is my code

javascript with ajax

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
                     var cuid= "{{ $cuid }}" ; //var cuid is my array value .
                     console.log(cuid);
                     getBranchAjax(cuid);

                 });



                      function getBranchAjax( cuid  ){
                $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
                        }
                    });
                $.ajax({
                    url:"{{ route('reporting.getCategoryAjax',['cuid']) }}",
                    method:'GET',
                    data:{cuid:cuid},
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(data){

                        console.log(data.category[0].irel__ref_category);
                       // console.log(data.branch.length);

                    },
                    fail: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('request failed');
                    }
                })
            }
```

controller

```
 public function getCategoryAjax(Request $request){

            $custid = $_GET['cuid'];
            if($custid != ''){
                $data = $this->hdrelcustcategory->findCustByID($custid);

            }


            return response()->json([
                'category' =>$data
            ]);
        }
```

model

```
public function irel_RefCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsto(RefCategory::class,'cc_category_code','Ct_Code');
    }

    public function findCustByID($custid){
        $relcustcat = $this->select('cc_category_code')
                           ->distinct()
                           ->where('cc_customer_id',$custid)
                           ->where('cc_status_rec','R01')
                           ->orderby('cc_category_code','ASC')
                           ->with(['irel_RefCategory' =>function($query){
                                $query->select('Ct_Code','Ct_Level','Ct_Abbreviation','Ct_Description','Ct_Parent')
                                      ->where('Ct_Status_Rec','R01');
                           }]);
        return $relcustcat->get();
    }
```

the error in console is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'irel__ref_category' of
>   undefined at Object.success (199,143,128:138) at i
>   (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2) at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith]
>   (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2) at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4) at
>   XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: sorry...  >the error in console is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'irel__ref_category' of undefined
    at Object.success (199,143,128:138)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this `->whereIn('cc_customer_id',$custid)`

so the method will be like this,

```php
    public function findCustByID($custid){
        $relcustcat = $this->select('cc_category_code')
                           ->distinct()
                           ->whereIn('cc_customer_id',$custid)
                           ->where('cc_status_rec','R01')
                           ->orderby('cc_category_code','ASC')
                           ->with(['irel_RefCategory' =>function($query){
                                $query->select('Ct_Code','Ct_Level','Ct_Abbreviation','Ct_Description','Ct_Parent')
                                      ->where('Ct_Status_Rec','R01');
                           }]);
        return $relcustcat->get();
    }
```